# What can cause a static SQL query against a static data set take vastly different amount of time to complete?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, query-performance

I have this very strange issue on one of the production servers - a parameterless stored procedure is either taking 1-2 minutes or 45+ minutes to finish, and it seems completely random and not following any pattern. Here are the specific things:

I am doing all testing on my own copy of the production database, on the production server. Which means that the data is completely static, there are no other processes against the database, the query itself is also completely static (no parameters). The data set it is working with are 3 tables, 24 rows, 80000 rows and 4.5 million rows. The query was working perfectly fine on the old server, which had half the memory and CPU of the current one, and was running 2008 R2 (current build is 2014). The databases are exact copies of the old ones.

What I have tried so far:

1. Create additional indexes, rebuild the ones I have, update statistics
2. Set the compatibility level to 100
3. Force the query to use the cardinality estimater of 2008 R2
4. Force the query to run with different MAXDOP settings - 0,1,4,8,16,28 (we have 28 physical cores with hyperthreading, so 56 logical)
5. Compared execution plans for when it runs for 1 minute and when it runs for 45 minutes - they are completely identical, word for word, value for value.

I am completely out of ideas at this point and I am starting to believe that I am missing something very simple. Unfortunately, I cannot provide you with the query as I believe it is confidential.. Is it possible to give me any ideas without the query? As my last resort, I thought of forcing the query to use the execution plan, that is created when it runs for 1 minute.

UPDATE: Now other stored procedures started behaving like that, however I can now see a common thing. Here is the "theme" of all failing SPs:

They consist of three statements, all of which update 3 columns.
Statement 1 - bunch of nested loops, a correlated subquery, etc. - finishes every time
Statements 2 and 3 - absolutely the same as statement 1, however using a different currency rate and most importantly - they are updating only NULL values, which the previous statement left. I tried creating a filtering index, but it didn't help again.

Comment: What wait types do the slow runs get? Also why would forcing the plan help if they are identical? Have you diffed the XML to be sure?

Comment: SAN or Storage Array shared? Virtualization? Temperature?

Comment: There are no wait types - the query is marked as Running at all times - not blocked, not waiting for anything. I have not diffed the XML, but, as I said, I am really desperate already, and this is the only thing I have not tried.
As for the storage - it is SAN, however it is barely used, since the server has 768 GB of RAM - out of which, 700 are granted to the instance. The latency however is in the range of 15-20ms , when they are being used.
Cannot tell about the temperature sadly.. I am sure it is a physical server.

Comment: "There are no wait types"... what do you mean? How can there be no wait types? If a query is running, it's accumulating waits.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Then I do not know how to see them... I set up a trace with extended events, capturing locks and waits for this database, and nothing was inside. Also, the native Activity monitor shows no waits for this database. The query is in permanent Running state, not once have I seen the status as Runnable/Sleeping/Suspended

Comment: Other processes that were running at the same time? Any blocks/waits on another process during a long run?  during a long run have you tried sp_who2 to see what else is going on in the db?

Comment: @indiri No, this database is an inactive copy of the production database, I am using it solely for running this SP. But when the SP runs on the production database, there are no other processes against it as well.

Comment: Look at the the old and new execution plans and tell us what you see.

Comment: Now, one week later, I still cannot find the issue. The difference is, however, that now it either finishes in 1 minute or it never finishes (at least not for the 27 hours I left it running).
The wait types are all the same - SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD and CXPACKET (when ran parallel).
I could not compare the fast and slow plans, because, well, the slow plan actually never finished executing...

Comment: Restart the SQL Server service when you get a chance.  SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD and CXPACKET waits on a query that never completes that is not being blocked are, *in my experience*, an indicator that you've seen a bug in SQL Server.